# converse of Weyl criterion

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in L^1([0,1))$,suppose for all equi-distributed sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $[0,1)$,we have $$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Nf(a_k)=\int_0^1f.$$

Do we have that $f$ is Riemann integrable ?

Remark:
I can just prove if $f$ satisfies the above equality, then $f$ must be bounded.

Comment: I think so. I think it's the case that f is Riemann integrable iff it set of discontinuities is a set of measure 0. I don't have  a reference for that result. But, if its the case, suppose f is not Riemann integrable. Take a sequence that is known to behave nicely with all sets of positive  measure, say irrational translation mod 1.   When it it is in the discontinuity set it should be possible to alter it to pick up the lim sup or lim inf resp.